# Swift code completion isn't working

Tags: xcode, swift, code-completion

I installed **Xcode 6.0 beta** and downloaded the **iOS8** library Documentation.
but when i create a **Swift** project, try to typing code

```
func aa(){
    let format = NSDateFormatter()
    var pageData = format.
}
```

I find Xcode can't dot any property and function. Am I missing any step?

*The problem is sloved, typing a whitespace can aid code completion*

Comment: Can you post your whole file? Is the function within a class?

Comment: the problem is can't dot anything，like uiwindow

Comment: Same problem for me, whitespace does't help

Comment: Try restarting Xcode. You have to remember this is **beta** software and it's likely to be broken at this point. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com/) if it's consistently broken.

Answer (score 4):

It's append when you change the hardware type and you choose less than iphone5.

Choose Iphone 6 for example in the list at the right of the stop button and the code completion for 'format' will appear.

Comment: Probably a different problem than the OP, but I was seeing this too (code completion, etc. depended on simulator target chosen) and filed a bug report.  The answer was to delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache (while Xcode is closed).

Comment: I used @guywithmazda's solution and it works again, however, I don't want to do deletion every day!

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem and solve it by removing the non-ASCII char in comment (in my problem, it's a chinese char "年" automatically generated in comment by xcode).

btw. "typing a whitespace can aid code completion" doesn't work for me

Comment: I filed a bug on this (I had a checkmark in my file and it broke code completion) and it came back as a duplicate, so Apple knows about it. — I stress that the checkmark was not even in my code; like you, I found it was sufficient if it was in a comment to break code completion after that point.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a bug, your code works on my system (OS X 10.9). Note that when typing code, I sometimes see the code completion crash for two seconds and come back.

When trying a first project named "swift", code completion crashed in a infinite loop… beta bugs… I just had to name it something else to test the language.

Comment: yes, my system is osx 10.9.3, as u say, i create a project of the projectname without swift & test, no amazing happing, so bad

Comment: Sorry I can’t help more, the only case when I observed this same problem was when trying swift in a project named exactly "swift" as I already stated. If you experience the same problem with another cause, maybe it has something to do with the file path of your project, try a project with a simple name at a simple file path (like /Users/your_account/) without spaces and special characters in it… I know it seems stupid but the fact that a project named "swift" doesn’t work for me is already stupid. Also, to be sure that your environment is correct, a restart would not hurt… :-S

Comment: noliv, i found some tips on apple developer forums, u can type a whitespace, then u will see the code completion. my english is bad, hope u can understand,^_^, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You know, I've experienced something similar with Objective C projects in Xcode 6 Beta 1. It seems Apple have changed the default behaviour a bit:

In Xcode 5.x code would always automatically complete as you type, but in this early beta try pressing ESCAPE - that will bring up the list you're looking for. Works for me. Some code auto completes as you type (both in Swift and Objective C), but at times only ESCAPE will bring up what we're looking for.

I'm nor sure if this is expected behaviour or a bug (I'm guessing the latter).

I must admit that your code works fine on my system without this trick. Just make sure you have code completion setup under Xcode - Preferences - Text Editing:

[image]